# Shiny dataTableOutput won't show up if its is under tabItem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My Shiny APP has a simple structure looks like:

````
ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "My App"),

    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard",
                 selectInput('location', 'Please Select a Location', choices= c("A", "B", "C")),
                 downloadButton(outputId = 'download', lable = "Downlaod"),
        menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
    )),

    # dashboardBody first try (works no problem):
    dashboardBody(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'mytable'))

    # dashboardBody second try (data table does not appear):
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'mytable')),

        tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
          h2("Widgets tab content"))
  )))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$mytable<- DT::renderDataTable({```some calculation```})

  output$downloadcsv <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste0(sys.Date(),'-mytable.csv')},
    content = function(file) {write.csv(```the table from renderDataTable step```, file)}
)}
````

As you can see, the app includes two different "pages" where the first one is a data table depends on the `selectInput`.

My app runs perfectly if I don't wrap it with `tabItem`. However, once I write it under `tabItem`, the app only shows *"Widgets tab content"* which is the content of the second tab and does not populate the data table at all (while the download button still works).

I've also tried to add `class='active'` behind `tabName = "dashboard"`, but it still doesn't work. Plus, I'm not getting any error message.

I'm wondering if anyone knows which step did I go wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please correct where you have rendered "output$downloadcsv" in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the placement of the table. I have rendered input options outside the menuItem. Check this code below

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "My App"),



dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    selectInput('location', 'Please Select a Location', choices= c("A", "B", "C")),
    downloadButton(outputId = 'download.csv', lable = "Downlaod"),
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),

             menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")


    )),

  # dashboardBody first try (works no problem):
  #dashboardBody(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'mytable'))

  #dashboardBody second try (data table does not appear):
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'mytable')),

      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"))
    ))
))


server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$mytable<- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(head(iris))})

  output$downloadcsv <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste0(sys.Date(),'-mytable.csv')},
    content = function(file) {write.csv(head(iris), file)}
  )}

  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```